# Why is the magnetic field dependent on the current inside the Amperian Loop?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electrons, electric-current

I visited this website simulating the [magnetic field inside and around a pipe.](http://physics.bu.edu/~duffy/semester2/d14_ampere_cylinder.html) I understand that there is no current flowing at the center of the pipe, thus there is no magnetic field generated anywhere $r < a$. But, if there was an electron flowing on the inner surface of the pipe, wouldn't that generate a magnetic field that would penetrate the area below the pipe's smaller radius, $a$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule about the magnetic field in the center of a current carrying pipe being zero assumes that the pipe is symmetric and the current flowing in the pipe is evenly distributed along it circumference.

Under these conditions, the magnetic field inside the pipe, which could be obtained by adding magnetic fields of millions of individual parallel currents distributed around the pipe, would be zero, because these fields would cancel each other.

It would be difficult to make a single electron to move along the inner surface of a conductive pipe without making other electrons to move as well, but it is certainly possible to induce an asymmetric current into the pipe and, because it is asymmetric, end up with some magnetic field inside it. But, in the light of the above, this does not represent a contradiction.

Comment: I see, so if I inserted gaps between sections of the cylinder, then I would be able to gather some field within the pipe because the fields generated by these numerous currents would not cancel each other out perfectly.

Comment: I would think so.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you again, I just needed to clarify something. You said, "The rule about the magnetic field in the center of a current carrying pipe." Did you mean in the dead center of the pipe? What if I chose a point more south of center? Would it then hold a net magnetic field, because there wouldn't be any symmetry around that point, right? Or is it still the same principle?

Comment: Still the same principle.